# VBA Move data to the left (4 columns need to be moved per row, may have blank within those 4 columns that need to be kept)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a a dataset that has a set of questions. However part of the data has been duplicated (4 columns) for the respondents. These need to be merged into just 4 columns based on heading they have (answer 1, answer 2, answer 3, answer4).

[Heres the example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB8En.jpg)

I've tried this:

```
Sub MoveLeft()
Dim r As Long, rws As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        rws = .Rows.Count
        r = 1
        On Error Resume Next
        Do
            .Rows(r).Resize(8000).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            r = r + 8000
        Loop While r <= rws
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But It didn't keep the blanks I needed

Comment: Maybe this will make the process clearer
1) Look at each row starting at A$F
2)First first non blank along that row
3)Copy The first nonblank, along with the three cells to the right of it
4) Move these four cells to ?F:?I of that row 
5) After doing this, delete the extra column after starting from J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to be able to do that in groups of 8000 rows. Each row needs to be done individually.

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r As Long, pos As Long
    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        With Intersect(.Range("F:AC"), .UsedRange.Cells)
            For r = 2 To .Rows.Count
                .Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, 4).ClearContents
                pos = .Cells(r, 1).End(xlToRight).Column - .Cells(r, 1).Column
                If pos <= .Columns.Count Then
                    pos = Application.Floor(pos, 4) + 1
                    .Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, 4) = .Cells(r, pos).Resize(1, 4).Value2
                End If
            Next r
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think I'm not adding it into the code correctly as It's not having the desired affect. Also when you say 'discard the first 5 columns, thats not my problem. I should have added to the diagram that the first 5 columns are fully correct and have values in every cell. My problem is that there are a set of 4 answers that need to be shifted left for each row. But sometimes there are gaps (if the respondent didn't answer one of the four questions). I need to keep these gaps so the answers are in the right structure in the blue columns on the picture.

Comment: You are not going to be able to do that in groups of 8000 rows. Each row needs to be done individually.

Comment: Ah ok thanks! I got that code from using google, sorry about that >.<. If its ok to ask, how would I adapt it to check every row?

Comment: I've deleted the groups of 8000 part (step 8000), but the data is still getting changed as its being moved. For example if there is a group of four answers such as [???], [???], [Blank], [???] It now equals [???], [???], [???], [Blank]

Comment: Ok you are an absolute God Jeeped!! It worked for the most part. How would I extend the intersect so it was until the last end of the row (as some values are beyond the AC column, and in the future it could grow further in that direction).

Comment: Well, if it was me, I'd adjust `.Range("F:AC")`.

Comment: Thanks. I know I must sound incredibly stupid... I just have the IT Crowd running in my head with the look of disgust they have when people ask for help >.<. You've been a lifesaver Jeeped

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere. I figured you just got excited with the results and overlooked that line of code.

Comment: ah well technically it would be good to have a solution that can scale without user input, but this gets the job done. Thanks once again.

Comment: Just change it to `Intersect(.Range("F:XFD"), .UsedRange.Cells)`, that should cover expansion while removing the first 5 columns from consideration..